# Extending functions to tuples

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++17, variadic

### Intro:

Imagine you have defined addition on types `A` and `B` with function `A add(A,A)` and `B add(B,B)`. Now, you would like to have an addition function on tuple of these types, like `tuple<A,B> add(tuple<A,B>,tuple<A,B>)`.

When we generalize this problem, we would like to extend an existing function working on some types to a function working on tuples of these types.

I call this extension function `static_container_functor` and the following code demonstrate its use:

```
int main() {

  std::tuple<double, int> t1{3.14159, -1}, t2{2.71828, 2};

  auto print = [](auto x) { std::cout << x << " "; };
  auto tuple_print = static_container_functor(print);
  tuple_print(t1); // prints "3.14159 -1 " and returns void instead of std::tuple<void,void> which is not possible

  std::cout << std::endl;

  auto add       = [](auto &&x, auto &&... y) { return (x + ... + y); };
  auto tuple_add = static_container_functor(add);
  auto t3 = tuple_add(t1, t1, t2); // t3 is of type std::tuple<double,int>
  tuple_print(t3);                 // prints "9.00146 0 "

  return 0;
}
```

I hope that it is clear to you by now what I'm trying to solve.

One way to think about `static_container_functor` is that it is somewhat glorified `for_each` for `std::tuple`.

### What I would like to know:

I would like to know how can I possibly improve my code and whether I'm missing handling some cases. Also, I'm have attempted to do perfect forwarding and I do not know how to test if it works.

Furthermore, I have not employed the standard trick with `std::index_sequence` in the main implementation of `static_container_functor` but did a small variation of it to keep all of the code together in one function. I would like to know what do you think about it?

How to handle `constexpr`? In the example, how can I achieve that the tuple `t3` can be `constexpr` when `t1` and `t2` are `constexpr`?

The function is called `static_container_functor` and not `tuple_functor` because I would like to extend it such that is works on `std::variant` and `std::array`. Ideally on anything that implements `std::get<>`. Any tips in that direction would be great.

Right now I'm doing a partial check, with `static_assert`, that the input arguments are really `std::tuple`s. Would you recommend using SFINAE like in this [post](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2016/03/21/concepts-without-concepts/)? However, for that I would need that`std::enable_if`  works with automatic return type deduction.

### Code:

https://godbolt.org/g/eWKxLo

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <std::size_t... I>
constexpr auto integral_sequence_impl(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
  return std::make_tuple((std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>{})...);
}

template <std::size_t N, typename Indices = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
constexpr auto integral_sequence = integral_sequence_impl(Indices{});

template <typename Op>
auto static_container_functor(Op &&op) {
  return [&op](auto &&c, auto &&... d) {
    /* here I should add a test that c and d... are really tuples */

    constexpr int N = std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(c)>>;
    static_assert(
        (true == ... ==
         (N == std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(d)>>)),
        "All of the arguments must have the same length!");

    auto implementation = [&](auto... I) {
      auto slice = [&](auto idx) {
        return std::forward_as_tuple(std::get<idx>(c), std::get<idx>(d)...);
      };

      auto result = [&](auto idx) {
        return std::apply(op, std::forward<decltype(slice(idx))>(slice(idx)));
      };
      auto zero = std::integral_constant<size_t, 0>{};

      if constexpr /* Are all return types are void? Return void*/
          ((std::is_same_v<void, decltype(result(I))> && ... && true)) {

        (result(I), ...);
        return;

      } else /* All other cases. Return std::tuple  */ {
        using ReturnType = std::tuple<decltype(result(I))...>;
        return ReturnType{result(I)...};
      }
    };

    return std::apply(implementation, integral_sequence<N>);
  };
}

int main() {

  std::tuple<double, int> t1{3.14159, -1}, t2{2.71828, 2};

  auto print = [](auto x) { std::cout << x << " "; };

  auto tuple_print = static_container_functor(print);
  tuple_print(t1); // prints "3.14159 -1 " and returns void

  std::cout << std::endl;

  auto add       = [](auto &&x, auto &&... y) { return (x + ... + y); };
  auto tuple_add = static_container_functor(add);
  auto t3 = tuple_add(t1, t1, t2); // t3 is of type std::tuple<double,int>
  tuple_print(t3);                 // prints "9.00146 0 "

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Compilation warnings

> ```
>    auto zero = std::integral_constant<size_t, 0>{};
> ```

What's this for?  It doesn't seem to be used, and removing it doesn't affect operation.

With that fixed, I get a nice clean compilation with my usual warnings `g++ -std=c++17 -g -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -Weffc++`.

---

## Includes and namespaces

`<array>` and `<iostream>` aren't required by the template, so shouldn't go with it when moved to a header.  To make that clear, I'd defer including them until just before `main()`.

`integral_sequence_impl()` and `integral_sequence` are internals, so should go into a "details" namespace that's not part of the public interface.

---

## Cleverness

This is probably too cute:

> ```
> constexpr int N = std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(c)>>;
> static_assert(
>     (true == ... ==
>      (N == std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(d)>>)),
>     "All of the arguments must have the same length!");
> ```

It looks like we believe in a Python-style chainable `==` operator, although that's not what's actually happening here.  I think that could trip up future maintainers, who may try to "correct" it.

I'd prefer to replace it with this more-transparent equivalent using `&&`:

```
constexpr auto N = std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(c)>>;
static_assert((... &&
               (N == std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(d)>>)),
              "All of the arguments must have the same length!");
```

(I changed `N` to be `auto`, since the standard leaves the type of `std::tuple_size` unspecified.)

---

## Simplifications

We don't need `&& true` at the end of the `std::is_same_v` fold expression.; `&& ...` is sufficient.  Actually, I think we really ought to be using `|| ...`, for those rare cases where only some overloads return `void`.

We could inline `slice()` (but then need a comment to replace the informative name):

```
    auto result = [&](auto idx) {
        return std::apply(op, std::forward_as_tuple(std::get<idx>(c), std::get<idx>(d)...));
        //                          ^^^ slice of idx'th element from from each input ^^^
    };
```

---

## Tests

The definition of `add` can be simplified:

```
auto add = []( auto&&... x) { return (x + ...); };
```

It would be good to see tests of functions that modify their arguments, to ensure that lvalues are passed correctly.  A simple variant is to change the type of `x` here:

```
  auto add = [](auto& x, auto&&... y) { return x = (x + ... + y); };
```

Along with

```
  tuple_print(t1);                 // prints "9.00146 0 "
  std::cout << '\n';
```

And the output does indeed match `t3`.

We can also create a test where the tuples to be operated on contain different types:

```
auto t1 = std::tuple<double, int>{3.14159, -1};
auto const t2 = std::tuple<float, unsigned char>{2.71828, 2};
```

I'm happy to report that this also works flawlessly (including in conjunction with the modifying test).

We could also include tests with other tuple-like types, such as `std::array` (I've confirmed that we can successfully mix types, using e.g. a tuple and an array of the same length - though a more realistic use-case would be a plain array and a `std::array`).

As indicated in the description, we're missing a test of the perfect forwarding.  One way to demonstrate this works it to perform a test on a non-copyable type, such as `std::unique_ptr`:

```
auto concat = []( auto&&... x) { return (*x + ...); };
auto s1 = std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<std::string>>{std::make_unique<std::string>("foo")};
auto s2 = std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<std::string>>{std::make_unique<std::string>("bar")};
tuple_print(static_container_functor(concat)(s1,s2));
std::cout << '\n';
```

---

## Style

Minor point, but most C++ authors would write the function accepting a forwarding reference as `…functor(Op&& op)` rather than `…functor(Op &&op)`.  The latter, being unusual, makes me double-scan that line every time I read it (and also couple of other places that have right-binding `&&`).